# Exist a theorem about the radius of convergence of a sequence of functions?

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I would like to know if there exists a theorem regarding the radius of convergence of a sequence of functions. E.g. I have a sequence of functions of the form $f_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k,n}x^{k}$ which all convergence absolutely for $|x|<R_{n}$, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}R_{n}=R$ exists then does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$ converge absolutely for $|x|<R$? Are there any additional conditions on the hypothesis, or does there exist any theorem which looks like the above statement?

Remark on the definition: the radius of convergence of a series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_{k}x^{k}$ is a real number $r$ such that the series converges absolutely for $|x|<r$ and diverges for $|x|>r$.

Comment: What do you mean by radius of convergence here? Are $f_n$ analytic?

Comment: By radius of convergence I mean a real number $R_{n}$ such that $f_{n}$ converges absolutely for $|x|<R_{n}$ and diverges for $|x|>R_{n}$.

Comment: Radius of convergence (as well as absolute convegence) is defined for functions of the form $\sum_n a_n x^n$ only. Are your $f_n$ of this form?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that, specifically: $f_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k,n}x^{k}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{n}(x) = f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$

Comment: No, you have to have that actually $lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$ actually exists too to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not generally hold. Define

$$a_{k,n} = \begin{cases} 1 &, k < n \\ R_n^{-k} &, k \geqslant n.\end{cases}$$

Then

$$f_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_{k,n}x^k$$

has radius of convergence $R_n$, and the limit function

$$f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty 1\cdot x^k$$

has radius of convergence $1$, regardless of the behaviour of $(R_n)$ [as long as $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} R_n > 0$, so we are sure to have some reasonable sense of limit beyond the pointwise limit of the coefficients].

We can ensure that the radius of convergence of $f$ is *at least* $R =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} R_n$ if we require that the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly on each closed disk $\overline{D_r(0)} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r\}$ for $0 < r < R$ [where we discard the finitely many $f_n$ with $R_n \leqslant r$]. Then the limit function is holomorphic at least on the disk $D_R(0)$, and thus its MacLaurin series has radius of convergence $\geqslant R$.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Can I now ask about the case in which $R_{n} \rightarrow R=0$, do we necessarily have that the limiting function $f$ diverges for all $x$?

Comment: The question is in what sense you take the limiting function. If you have $R_n \geqslant \varepsilon > 0$ for all $n$, then you can consider the pointwise limit [which may or may not exist] on the disk $\lvert z\rvert < \varepsilon$, and if it exists, you know whether you have an analytic function or not. In my example, under that condition, you have locally uniform convergence on a neighbourhood of $0$. If $R_n \to 0$, what do you do then? You can look at the formal series $\sum a_k x^k$ where $a_k = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{k,n}$ for all $k$, provided all these limits exist.

Comment: Then the explicit example in the answer shows that the series can have a radius of convergence that is strictly greater than $0$ [you can make the radius of convergence anything you want by a similar construction, even $\infty$]. But then you can't consider pointwise convergence except at the single point $0$.